# Get Attribute info with generics

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

actually, I can make a relation between a table field and a variable by doing this inside my OE:

```
public class MyOE
{
  [Column("AGE_FIELD")]
  public int ageField { get; set; }
}
```

My OE class just need to use this other class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ColumnAtt : Attribute
{
  private string name;

  public string Name
  {
    get { return name; }
  }

  public ColumnAtt (string name)
  {
     this.name = name;
  }  
}
```

Well, using the code above, Im doing a generic method that I will need to get the "Column" value. How I could do that?

Here is my method:

```
public void CompareTwoObjectsAndSaveChanges<TObjectType>(TObjectType objectA, TObjectType objectB )
{
    if(objectA.GetType() == objectB.GetType())
    {
       foreach (var prop in objectA.GetType().GetProperties())
       {
           if(prop.GetValue(objectA, null) != prop.GetValue(objectB, null))
           {
               string colvalue  = "";//Here I need to get the Column value of the attribute.
               string nameOfPropertyThatChanges = prop.Name;
               string objectAValue = prop.GetValue(objectA, null).ToString();
               string objectBValue = prop.GetValue(objectB, null).ToString();

           }
       }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use reflection to get the attributes applied to your object. If you know the attribute is always going to be `ColumnAtt`, then you can do something like this to get the value:

```
public void CompareTwoObjectsAndSaveChanges<TObjectType>(TObjectType objectA, TObjectType objectB )
{
    if(objectA.GetType() == objectB.GetType())
    {
       foreach (var prop in objectA.GetType().GetProperties())
       {
           if(prop.GetValue(objectA, null) != prop.GetValue(objectB, null))
           {
               // Get the column attribute
               ColumnAttr attr = (ColumnAttr)objectA.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttr), false).First();

               string colValue = attr.Name;
               string nameOfPropertyThatChanges = prop.Name;
               string objectAValue = prop.GetValue(objectA, null).ToString();
               string objectBValue = prop.GetValue(objectB, null).ToString();
           }
       }   
    }
}
```

This makes use of the [`GetCustomAttributes(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d.aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks, bro !!  For any reason, the conditional if(prop.GetValue(objectA, null) != prop.GetValue(objectB, null)), I dont know why.. Im comparing the same values and its saying that they are different ( both upper cases and same typing.)

Comment: @Dan-SP What are the values it's trying to compare? It's possible that using the `!=` operator, it's not comparing correctly.

Comment: Im trying to compare two simple strings.. they are with exactly the same value.

Comment: When comparing string equality, I prefer using [`String.Equals(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals.aspx). If you don't care about casing, you can use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` as one of the arguments. Might be worth trying it to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks, man ! Sincel I dont recieve strings all the time, the suggested solution you put as: `prop.GetValue(objectA, null) != prop.GetValue(objectB, null)` works well.. How would you sugest to change it to work with strings too ? Thanks !

Comment: @Dan-SP You could always do a type check to see what you are working with, then have a series of method overloads to compare values of different types. See [here](http://pastebin.com/w7nkX4Ph) for an example of what I mean. You might want to do a test on string comparisons in a separate project, though, and see if the `!=` and `==` operators *do* work on strings; both when in string format and when stored as an object.

Answer (score 6):

Use reflection:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyOE zz = new MyOE { ageField = 45 };

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in zz.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            // Gets the first attribute of type ColumnAttribute for the property
            // As you defined AllowMultiple as true, you should loop through all attributes instead.
            var attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<ColumnAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (attribute != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(attribute.Name);    // Prints AGE_FIELD
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: that's exactly what i was going to post :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var columnAtt = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomAtt),true).Cast<ColumnAtt>().FirstOrDefault();
```

(fixed)