# Get Column Name of entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, columnattribute

I'm using Entity Framework and here is what the metadata looks like for one of the tables.

```
    [Column("pp_account")]
    public string Account { get; set; }
    [Column("pp_added")]
    public DateTime? AddDate { get; set; }
    [Column("pp_auser")]
    public string AddUpdateUserName { get; set; }
    [Column("pp_cfalt")]
    public string AlternateForwardingNumber { get; set; }
```

I'm interested in getting the Column attribute name instead of the public name, i.e. display pp_added instead of "AddDate".  Here is a foreach loop I've written so far that almost gets me there

```
foreach(var field in _personal.GetType().GetProperties())
{
            sb.Append("\nName            : " +  field.Name + "\n");
            sb.Append("Type        : " + field.PropertyType.Name + "\n");
            sb.Append("Attributes:  " + field.Attributes + "\n");
            sb.Append("Value       : " + field.GetValue(_personal, null) + "\n");
}
```

Here is what is returned:

```
Name:  AddDate
Type:  Nullable'1
Attributes:  None
Value:  5/2/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

What I would like to get returned is

```
Name:  pp_added
Type:  Date
Value:  5/2/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

How do I access the `[Column("pp_added")]` to get `pp_added` instead of the public `Name`?

Comment: You need to use reflection. See more in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113020/get-attribute-info-with-generics

Comment: Reflection-based approach won't work in fluent API case. You need to explore EF metadata.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
foreach(var field in _personal.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   sb.Append("\nName       : " +  field.GetCustomAttribute<ColumnAttribute>().Name + "\n");
   sb.Append("Type        : " + field.PropertyType.Name + "\n");
   sb.Append("Value       : " + field.GetValue(_personal, null) + "\n");
}
```

The `ColumnAttribute` is in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` namespace.

Comment: But he says "field.Name" does not return the expected value.

Comment: I'm not using `Name` property of the field but of the column attribute

Comment: Thank you very much.  That did the trick.  I am so grateful for your help.

Comment: Does this work for anyone ?  For me, "field.GetValue(_personal,null)"  always returns the name of the C# variable, rather than the value in Column("xxxx")

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Alexander's answer, this will get the underlying type for the nullable type:

```
sb.Append("Type        : " + (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(field.PropertyType) ?? field.PropertyType).Name + "\n");
```

[Nullable.GetUnderlyingType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype(v=vs.110).aspx) will return the underlying Type if it is nullable (i.e. it will return `DateTime`, if given `DateTime?`), or return null if it's not nullable. Hence, the `??` expression.

Comment: That was going to be my next question if I couldn't find it.  Thanks for the answer ahead of time and saving me the 2 days of looking and trying.  I very much appreciate it.